# Propiedad path y split dan error al momento de subir una imagen al servidor de HEROKU

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, express, heroku

Tengo problemas con las propiedades path y split al subir imagenes, creo que esas funciones de javaScript no son permitidas con HEROKU, quisiera saber si tambien les ha pasado el mismo problema que ami... o si detallan algun error en el codigo o tienen conocimiento del motivo del error.

Errores en el servidor de HEROKU

```
2021-02-04T01:03:23.505925+00:00 app[web.1]: POST /api/uploadPhotoProfile 500 3.148 ms - 148
2021-02-04T01:03:23.507503+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined
2021-02-04T01:03:23.507504+00:00 app[web.1]: at uploadPhotoProfile2 (/app/controllers/user.js:349:43)
2021-02-04T01:03:23.507505+00:00 app[web.1]: at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
2021-02-04T01:03:23.507506+00:00 app[web.1]: at next (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)



2021-02-04T01:03:23.505925+00:00 app[web.1]: POST /api/uploadPhotoProfile 500 3.148 ms - 148
2021-02-04T01:03:23.507503+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
2021-02-04T01:03:23.507504+00:00 app[web.1]: at uploadPhotoProfile2 (/app/controllers/user.js:376:33)
2021-02-04T01:03:23.507505+00:00 app[web.1]: at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
2021-02-04T01:03:23.507506+00:00 app[web.1]: at next (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
```

Cuando intento probar la misma función en mi local si sube la imagen sin problema, por lo que debe ser un tema de HEROKU

Corriendolo en el metodo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Les dejo el codigo en el controlador

```
User.Controller


    uploadPhotoProfile: function(req,res){
        //configurar el modulo mutiparty (subida de fichero)
    
        //recoger el fichero de la peticion
        var photoProfile = 'Avatar no subido...';
        
    
        if(!req.files){
    
            return res.status(404).send({
                status:'error',
                message: photoProfile
            });
        }
       // conseguir el nombre y la extension del archivo
       var file_path= req.files.photoProfile.path;
       var file_split = file_path.split('\\');
         
        //nombre del archivo
       var file_name= file_split[2];
       
       //Extension del archivo
       var ext_split = file_name.split('\.');
       var file_ext = ext_split[1];
    
       //comprobar extension(solo imagenes)
        if (file_ext != 'png' && file_ext !='jpg' && file_ext !='jpeg' && 
        file_ext !='gif' && file_ext !='JPG' && file_ext !='JPEG'&& file_ext !='PNG'){
            fs.unlink(file_path, () =>{
                
                return res.status(200).send({
                    status:'error',
                    message:'La Extension del Archivo no es valido',
                    file: file_ext
                    });
            });
    
        }else{
       //sacar el id del usuario identificado
            var userId= req.user.sub;
       //buscar y actualizar documentos de la bd
       User.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: userId}, {photoProfile : file_name}, {new:true}, (err, userUpdated)=>{
            
        if(err || !userUpdated){
    
            //devolver respuesta 
            return res.status(500).send({
                status:'error',
                message:'Error al guardar el usuario',
                    });
                }
            return res.status(200).send({
                status:'succes',
                user : userUpdated
                });
                
            });
      
        }
    },
```

Comment: Si haces debug y analizas esta línea: `var file_path= req.files.photoProfile.path;`, qué valor tiene la variable `file_path`? Por el error parece ser null y por eso podría darte error cuando tratas en la línea siguiente de hacer el `split`.

Comment: El detalle esta al momento de hacer el deployment en HEROKU, en la local si hace el upload de la imagen, por lo que no entiendo y si solamente realizo una funcion y capturo en un console.log la variable file_path, me trae la ruta completa en mi local, pero e el deploy me dice que la propiedad path esta indefinida.,. osea en mi local no tengo errores, realiza mi proceso normal... el detalle es cuando hago el deployment en HEROKU!

Comment: me esta llegando vacio el json en el heroku y en el local me trae los datos

2021-02-04T18:35:58.093275+00:00 app[web.1]: {}
2021-02-04T18:35:58.100777+00:00 app[web.1]: POST /api/uploadPhotoProfile2 500 10.950 ms - 148
2021-02-04T18:35:58.101960+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined
2021-02-04T18:35:58.101961+00:00 app[web.1]: at uploadPhotoProfile2 (/app/controllers/user.js:350:42)

El mismo meto en mi local probandolo con POSTMAN

{
    "status": "succes",
    "file": "uploads\\users\\L8LUj9D5oqAAifu7cV35tZxY.JPG"
}

Comment: ¿Quizás [https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted](este enlace) a la docu de Heroku te pudiera ayudar a lo que te está pasando?

Comment: Hola Sema, me da error el enlace que me enviaste!

Comment: Sema, estaba revisando y en mi local si reconoce el parametro req.files que se le envia por postman en HEROKU me trae un JSON vacío! Conexión a la base de datos establecida satisfactoriamente...
Servidor corriendo correctamente en la url: localhost:5000
{
  photoProfile: {
    fieldName: 'photoProfile',
    originalFilename: 'cv.png.JPG',
    path: 'uploads\\users\\AaAIBbAHjqHm5j08u1XrHvWP.JPG',

//HEROKU//

Comment: Ups, perdona Andrés, no me di cuenta; [enlace a la doc de Heroku](https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted) donde indica un problema similar al que te está ocurriendo al usar Heroku

Answer (score 0):

lo que realice para solventar mi problema era imprimir todas las variables path tenia en mi funcion a ver donde se estaba perdiendo la informacion.

```
2021-02-05T03:52:51.425793+00:00 app[web.1]: photoProfile: {
2021-02-05T03:52:51.425793+00:00 app[web.1]: fieldName: 'photoProfile',
2021-02-05T03:52:51.425794+00:00 app[web.1]: originalFilename: 'claro cuenta actual.JPG',
2021-02-05T03:52:51.425794+00:00 app[web.1]: path: 'uploads/users/HDA--yvj3mPzaByY5Ylf1hXO.JPG',
2021-02-05T03:52:51.425795+00:00 app[web.1]: headers: {
2021-02-05T03:52:51.425795+00:00 app[web.1]: 'content-disposition': 'form-data; name="photoProfile"; filename="claro cuenta actual.JPG"',
2021-02-05T03:52:51.425796+00:00 app[web.1]: 'content-type': 'image/jpeg'
2021-02-05T03:52:51.425796+00:00 app[web.1]: },
2021-02-05T03:52:51.425797+00:00 app[web.1]: size: 58809,
2021-02-05T03:52:51.425872+00:00 app[web.1]: name: 'claro cuenta actual.JPG',
2021-02-05T03:52:51.426140+00:00 app[web.1]: type: 'image/jpeg'
2021-02-05T03:52:51.426141+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2021-02-05T03:52:51.426141+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2021-02-05T03:52:51.426148+00:00 app[web.1]: uploads/users/HDA--yvj3mPzaByY5Ylf1hXO.JPG primer console
2021-02-05T03:52:51.426149+00:00 app[web.1]: [ 'uploads', 'users', 'HDA--yvj3mPzaByY5Ylf1hXO.JPG' ] segundo console
2021-02-05T03:52:51.426301+00:00 app[web.1]: HDA--yvj3mPzaByY5Ylf1hXO.JPG tercer console
2021-02-05T03:52:51.427017+00:00 app[web.1]: [ 'HDA--yvj3mPzaByY5Ylf1hXO.JPG' ] cuarto console
2021-02-05T03:52:51.427124+00:00 app[web.1]: undefined quinto console
```

Al tener en cuenta como estoy recibiendo el req.files que los separadores en windows son distintos a linux, para windows son dos barras invertidas, para linux es un slahs

Realice los cambios en mi consulta y elimine la linea que va despues del segundo split y le pase el otro metodo .pop() como se ve acontinuacion.

```
    var photoProfile = 'Avatar no subido...';
 

    if(!req.files){

        return res.status(404).send({
            status:'error',
            message: photoProfile
            
        });
    }
    console.log(req.files);

   // conseguir el nombre y la extension del archivo
   var file_path= req.files.photoProfile.path;
   console.log(file_path,'primer console');

   var file_split = file_path.split('/');
    console.log(file_split,'segundo console');

    //nombre del archivo
   var file_name= file_split[2];
   console.log(file_name,'tercer console');
   
   //Extension del archivo
   var ext_split = file_name.split('.').pop();
   console.log(ext_split,'cuarto console');

 

   //comprobar extension(solo imagenes)
    if (ext_split != 'png' && ext_split !='jpg' && ext_split !='jpeg' &&  ext_split !='gif' && ext_split !='JPG' && ext_split !='JPEG'&& ext_split !='PNG'){
        fs.unlink(file_path, () =>{
            return res.status(200).send({
                status:'error',
                message:'La Extension del Archivo no es valido',
                file: file_ext
                });
        });
```

Con esto ya pude solventar el problema que tenia paras subir imagenes.